# Órden de los puntos de una línea sobre geom_density_ridge()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Estoy graficando la distribución de los residuos de un modelo lineal. Para mantener el ejemplo mínimo digamos que el modelo tiene un solo predictor. La aproximación convencional es un qqplot, como los que produce `plot(lm(y~x, data = foo))`, pero estoy experimentando con `ggridges::geom_density_ridge()`. La idea es graficar la densidad de los residuos para los deciles de x (en el modelo) y visualizar heterocedasticidad. Un código similar al que estoy usando (y que servirá para reproducir el problema) es este:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)
mtcars %>% 
  select(hp, mpg) %>% 
  mutate(decil_hp = factor(ntile(hp, 10))) %>% 
  mutate(estimado_mpg = predict(lm(mpg~hp, data = .)), 
         residuos = mpg - estimado_mpg) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = residuos, y = decil_hp)) + 
  geom_density_ridges() -> p

p
```

Que produce:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta acá todo bien, los residuos son heterocedásticos, etc.

El problema con el código surge cuando quiero generar una línea que una las medias  de *x* (en el gráfico según `aes(x= )` por cada decil (en el gráfico mapeado a *y*). Buscando encontré en SO en inglés una [solución](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52713272/adding-a-mean-to-geom-density-ridges) parcial, que me permite graficar puntos o líneas verticales en el valor máximo de cada kernel de densidad. Dado que que `geom_density_ridges()` hace algunas transformaciones internas es complicado dar con la media exacta, pero se puede encontrar fácilmente el valor máximo. Si los residuos agrupados por decil se distribuyen como una normal la media y el máximo de densidad deberían coincidir o estar suficientemente cerca. Mis datos tienen un n más grande que `mtcars` y están mejor comportados, así que ese no es el problema principal, aunque agradecería ayuda para este problema.

El problema principal es que quiero graficar una línea con `geom_line()` que una a esos puntos y lo logro, pero los resultados quedan desordenados. Es decir, en lugar de unir al valor máximo de cada decil del 1 al 10 la línea está ordena, aparentemente, por el valor máximo de densidad. El resultado es un zigzag y no es lo que estoy buscando. Quizás con el código y el gráfico quede más claro:

```
# Extraigo los datos del gráfico y filtro los valores máximos
ggplot_build(p) %>% purrr::pluck("data", 1) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  filter(density == max(density)) %>% 
  ungroup() -> maximos

#Agrego al gráfico original la línea
p + labs(title = "x y x transpuestas", 
         y = "Decil hp",
         x = expression(y-hat(y))) +
geom_line(data = maximos, aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Probé con las soluciones obvias: pasar y a factor y darle el orden, poner `group = 1` dentro del `aes()` de `geom_line()`  sin el resultado esperado.

Las preguntas por orden de importancia:

1. ¿cómo puedo obtener la misma línea del segundo gráfico, pero ordenada desde el decil 1 al 10 (o a la inversa), de modo que no haya "saltos" del 1 al 10, luego al 8, al 2 y así?
2. ¿Es posible extraer la media de un `geom_density_ridges() en lugar de conformarme con el valor más alto, que podría o no ser la media?
3. ¿Hay alguna manera de hacer lo que busco directamente, sin extraer los datos para la línea de un objeto `ggplot()` previamente hecho?

Agradezco de antemano a esta comunidad la atención, el tiempo que pudieran dedicar y especialmente cualquier respuesta que me ayude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Para la grafica una alternativa es usar `geom_segment`

```
aux<-maximos[-10,]
aux$xend<-maximos$x[-1]
aux$yend<-maximos$y[-1]
#Agrego al gráfico original la línea
p + labs(title = "x y x transpuestas", 
         y = "Decil hp",
         x = expression(y-hat(y))) +
  geom_segment(data = aux, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend))
```

[image]

En el punto número 2 en realidad no lo se. Para el tres podrías guardar las estimaciones y los residuos en un df en lugar de calcularlas directamente al hacer el gráfico, y luego calcular la media exacta.

Espero que te ayude en algo. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, para el problema principal la solución funciona. `geom_line()` a veces de un poco de trabajo y sale mejor con un primitivo.